# Errors when using Codable - Swift

Tags: swift, codable, encodable

I am using `Codable` to try to `Encode` JSON to a Model but I get two errors.
***Value of type 'KeyedEncodingContainer' has no member 'encoder'***

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

struct NewCustomer : Codable {

    var firstName :String
    var lastName :String


    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
    }

    func encode(to encoder :Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encoder(self.firstName, forKey: .firstName)  // error here
        try container.encoder(self.lastName, forKey: .lastName)  // error here
    }
}

let customer = NewCustomer(firstName: "Jake", lastName: "Reynolds")

let encodedCustomerJSON = try! 
JSONEncoder().encode(customer)

print(encodedCustomerJSON)

print(String(data: encodedCustomerJSON, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `encoder` to `encode` on the two lines giving errors. Please note that the line above (i.e. var container...) will keep `encoder`.

```
try container.encode(self.firstName, forKey: .firstName)
try container.encode(self.lastName, forKey: .lastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned it's a typo `encode` vs. `encoder`:

```
try container.encode(...
```

Practically you don't need to specify `CodingKeys` and the encoding method at all in this case, this is sufficient:

```
struct NewCustomer : Codable {
    var firstName, lastName : String
}
```